# add two entry for every row - Linq C#

Tags: c#, linq

it is my query:

```
from customer in db.tblCustomers
select new
{
     ID = customer.CustomerID,
     Mobile = customer.Mobile1,
     LastName = customer.Family
};
```

for every customer there is tow mobile phones, I need to add a new entry if the second mobile phone is not null. also I should change the LastName for second entry to something like "Second Mobile". How can I get two different entry from one customer using linq query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the same generated type you can't have one with only one property of phone number and another with two. You can do:

```
from customer in db.tblCustomers
select new
{
     ID = customer.CustomerID,
     Mobile = customer.Mobile1,
     SecondMobile = customer.Mobile2, // will be null if no second mobile exists
     LastName = customer.Family
};
```

Otherwise what you can do is create a custom type `Customer` that will have a single phone number and a derived type `ExtendedCustomer` with two - and just instantiate the one or the other. Something along the psudo:

```
from customer in db.tblCustomers
select customer.Mobile2 != null ? new Customer(...) : new ExtendedCustomer(...);
```

---

If what you mean is having two different objects in the resulted collection then use union:

```
List<Customer> result = new List<Customer>();
foreach(var item in db.tblCustomers)
{
    result.Add(new Customer(/*data for first mobile phone*/);
    if(item.Mobile2 != null) 
    {
        result.Add(new Customer(/*data for second mobile phone*/);
    }
}
```

Comment: as you said he needs to have another field for second mobile number or have a parentId field, either way what is he doing is wrong.  you are right =) never mind.

Comment: I don't think it solves the given problem. Why accepted? Below is the correct solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/44612471/5432796

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try this if it helps?

```
var customers = db.tblCustomers.SelectMany(x => x.GetMultipleRow()).ToList();
```

GetMultipleRow is an extension method as below.

```
public static class CustomerExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Customer> GetMultipleRow(this Customer cust)
    {
        yield return new Customer { CustomerID = cust.CustomerID, Mobile1 = cust.Mobile1, Family = cust.Family };
                                    /* Data for first mobile*/
        if (cust.Mobile2 != null)
            yield return new Customer { CustomerID = cust.CustomerID, Mobile1 = cust.Mobile2, Family = cust.Family };
                                        /* Data for second mobile*/
    }
}
```